# full list of EKG2 plugins dependencies

Tags: compile, dependencies

Every time I want to compile and install ekg2 I'm struggling with dependencies. Right now I somehow managed (again) to install all needed packages. Still I have no idea which of packaged i installed were really needed (ie. to make ncurses work I install all packakes containing ncurses in name in repository). Despite every time I eventually do compile and install ekg2 I still have no idea which packages were required to make it work so the question remains:

**What is full list of required packages to compile all ekg2 plugins?**

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to help, although I am not an EKG2 user, so bear with me.

Most Linux distributions list the dependencies of packages.

The archlinux distribution has a modest [list](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=45163) of dependencies :
aspell giflib gnutls gpgme gpm libgadu libidn libjpeg python2

The Debian distribution has a very long [list of dependencies](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze-backports/ekg2) :

```
debhelper : helper programs for debian/rules  
libncursesw5-dev : developer's libraries for ncursesw  
python-dev : header files and a static library for Python (default)  
python-central : register and build utility for Python packages  
libperl-dev : Perl library: development files  
libssl-dev : SSL development libraries, header files and documentation  
libgnutls-dev : the GNU TLS library - development files  
libaspell-dev : Development files for applications with GNU Aspell support  
libgadu-dev : Gadu-Gadu protocol library - development files  
libexpat1-dev : XML parsing C library - development kit  
libgpmg1-dev : transitional dummy package which can be safely removed also a virtual package provided by libgpm-dev  
libidn11-dev : Development files for GNU Libidn, an IDN library  
libxosd-dev : X On-Screen Display library - development  
libsqlite3-dev : SQLite 3 development files  
python : interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)  
xsltproc : XSLT 1.0 command line processor  
docbook-xsl : stylesheets for processing DocBook XML to various output formats  
doxygen : Documentation system for C, C++, Java, Python and other languages  
libgtk2.0-dev : Development files for the GTK+ library  
libgpgme11-dev : GPGME - GnuPG Made Easy  
zlib1g-dev : compression library - development  
quilt : Tool to work with series of patches
```

Your case might lie anywhere between these two. The best way to find out is to look up the description of the EKG2 package in the Linux distribution that you are actually using (although that might not include the packages used by all the plugins).

In any case, doesn't your Linux distribution include a binary release of the EKG2 package ?
Installing the binary release through a package manager will automatically take care of the dependencies (if it includes all the plugins).

Comment: To the down-voter: If you can do better, then do so. If not, then let me try to find out if I can help this guy without interference.

Comment: I just corrected that, thanks for your hard work answering on this site :) PS: I'm not the guy who downvoted you in the first place.

Comment: EKG2 don't exist in Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS repos (with exception for Debian Experimantal). I'm trying to compile EKG2, not install it from package. Also: packages listed are not sufficient to compile all plugins.

Comment: Can't you make a list of all libraries used by all the plugins? That would give you too many, of course, but you shouldn't really care. What is the format of these plugins, anyway ?

Comment: If I could I woudnt ask here.

Comment: If you have the makefile(s) for the plugins you could get the list of libraries from the link command. Otherwise, if the plugins are executables or shared libraries then the list of used shared libraries can be created by `nm -D`.

Comment: You don't know what ekg2 is, do you?

Comment: Never used it, but a makefile is a makefile, a program is a program (same for library), and Linux has tools to handle these. It should be a simple matter to create the existing list from the existing compiled plugins or the makefile(s), and a safe bet that this list would not change unless new plugins are added.